# Geo location is not accurate in my app

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, geolocation

Geo location is not accurate in my ionic app. It shows near by location. But not the exact point. I checked 'locate' (cross-hair) in google map app. But its same as my app. Not the exact point. But in google map, when i tried get directions from 'Your location' to a certain place, it started exactly from my point. How can get the accurate location like in google map 'Get direction > Your location'?

Comment: did you used LocationServices.FusedLocationApi?

Comment: This is the one iam using  var options = { timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 250};
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,onError,options);

Comment: Bryan, thanks for your help. Wlll LocationServices.FusedLocationApi solve my problem? Will that work in ionic framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just replaced

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,onError,options);

with

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess,onError,options);